# Generating config file for symmetric-encryption

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use [symmetric-encryption](https://rocketjob.github.io/symmetric-encryption/) ina Ruby project but I'm having a hard time to generate the configuration file.

I have tried to use the `symmetric-encryption --generate` command as stated in the configuration guide but it is not working.

`symmetric-encryption: No such file or directory`.

I have also tried to install the binstub and run `bin/symmetric-encryption --generate --app-name my_app --environments "development,test,preprod,acceptance,production"` but I get

`Unknown switches '--generate, --app-name, --environments'`

Any ideas how to generate the file or where I can get a sample?

Thanks

Comment: are you using this in a Rails project?  Did you do the obvious add gem to gemfile and run `bundle install` ?  Also if you run the commands in the example here?  https://rocketjob.github.io/symmetric-encryption/configuration.html#example

Comment: `bundle exec symmetric-encryption --generate  ...` did the trick for me.